# Github repository won't pull or push

Tags: git, github, push, commit, pull

so basically I:

1. Made a Github repository and cloned it to my desktop
2. Modified the README.md file from Github and forgot to pull it to my desktop
3. Made over 10 commits from like 2 hours of code

Git won't let me push:

```
![rejected]
error: failed to push some refs
```

Git won't let me pull:

```
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

What can I do?

Comment: I guess you modified the README.md locally? Did you try to look at your conflicts with `git diff` and try to fix them?

Comment: you can override readme by doing the force push. Else you can go for the rebase onto.

Comment: Fix the merge conflicts (edit the sections in the README with letters like `<<<<` or `>>>>`), stage the files, commit and push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch the changes from the server and then merge or rebase them.

```
git fetch --all
git rebase origin/master
git mergetool (most likely you will have some conflicts)
git push origin master
```

You can solve the conflict manually or with mergetool. For manual you will change the files and run `git add <file>; git rebase --continue`

Or more simple solution for you can be to force push it and write readme again

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: please, do not instruct people with little confidence with git to use the `--force` option. Forcing is something an experienced user should use as little as possible. A novice user should never ever use force: this will end up opening new questions here on SO like "my history disappeared from the remote, how to fix".

Comment: git merge worked like a charm, thank you very much!